# Jquery dialog box error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a dialog box to display and submit a enquiry form on my page.I am having problem when I try to call it **again and again**.The first time everything works fine and the form s submitted successfully.But if I click the GO button(added html below).I get an error for this line document.
**EDITED:**

```
<div class="hidden" id="dialog">
    <form action="index.php" class="testForm" id="testForm">
        <div class="name" id="name">
            <div class="displayName" id="dispName">Name</div>
            <div class="textName" id="viewName"><input type="text" class="fname" id="fullName" /></div>
            <div class="hide" id="nameErr"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="address" id="addressDetails">
            <div class="displayAddress" id="dispAddress">Address</div>
            <div class="textAddress" id=""><input type="text" class="taddress" id="fullAddress" /></div>
            <div class="hide" id="addressErr"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="submitForm" ><input type="button" class="submitDetails" id="submitInfo" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="validateAndSubmitForm()"/>
        <a name="Close" onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('close');">Close</a>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>
```

Javascript\jquery

```
function submitEnquiryForProperty()
```

{

```
document.forms.testForm.reset();

$("#dialog").dialog({
                modal:true,
                resizable:false,
                autoOpen:false,
                width:260,
        });
openDialog();
```

}

```
  function openDialog(){
$("#dialog").dialog("open");    
  }

  function closeDialog(){
$("#dialog").dialog("close");   
 }
```

Callback function on form submit

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"processForm.php",
            data:"name="+name+"&address="+address,
            dataType:"html",

            success:function(msg){
                if(msg=="success"){
                    $("#dialog", window.parent.document).html("<div class='pad5'><div class='flt' style='padding-left:3px; width:235px;'><div class='thanx_msg'>Thank you for submitting the details. <br /><div class='spacer5'>&nbsp;</div><span class='gre'>Our Sales team shall revert to your query soon.</span></div></div><div class='spacer5'>&nbsp;</div><div style='padding-left:3px;' class='text'><strong>You can also:</strong></div><div style='margin-left:20px; line-height:20px;'>&bull; Apply for a <a href='homeloan.php'>Home Loan</a><br />&bull; Visit <a href='http://www.proptiger.com'>proptiger.com</a> for more properties<br />&bull; See our <a href='http://www.proptiger.com/blog'>Blog</a> for latest updates</div></div><br/><div class='msg' style='color:red;'>Click to close the box</div>");

                    $(function(){
                                $('#dialog').click(function() {
                                    closeDialog();
                                });
                            });

                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Operation cannot be completed,please try again");        
                }
            }
```

But I am facing the same problem.Error at the `.reset()` line.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I achieved it in a different way.May be a work around(not sure).What I did is added another `<div>` to the html and used it for displaying the success message on callback.So the div with form remained intact and was not changed in the content as earlier.Please let me know if it is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated answer

If you want to have a reusable dialog, do it like this:

1. Include the dialog element (almost assuredly a `<div>`) in your initial HTML. Use a CSS class so that it will not be immediately visible, for example:

   ```
   HTML:
   <div id="dialog" class="hidden">...</div>

   CSS:
   .hidden { display: none }
   ```
2. Unconditionally call `$("#dialog").dialog(options)` from Javascript immediately after the page loads. Be sure to set `autoOpen: false` in the options.
3. Whenever you want to display the dialog, use `$("#dialog").dialog("open")`.
4. Whenever you want to hide the dialog, use `$("#dialog").dialog("close")`.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 as much as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply but I have already tried that and it doesn't work!!! :( I checked the watch for `document.getElementById("enqFormProp")` and initially it shows all the form attributes but after the first submit it doesn't.Can't find a way to debug it too!!

Comment: @forummember: I don't know why that happens exactly because the code is a bit convoluted, although of course there is a reason :) Check out the updated answer for a walkthrough approach and do it that way.

Comment: So in my case the `function showSubsReqForm(title,perpose,pagename)` would go inside the unconditional call part and I would be using `$("#dialog").dialog("open")` `$("#dialog").dialog("close")` for calling the dialog box.

Comment: @forummember: Yes, although I do not have the slightest idea why you are doing anything else other than calling `.dialog()` in there.

Comment: Its the form validation part and those are the error divs that I am setting to blank,to clear any error message.Added a portion of my form which holds the first 2-3 divs.

Comment: Tried it for a smaller scenario as suggested by your method,but still getting the same error!! :( I hope its not something foolish I am doing.I have updated the question please go through and suggest something.

Comment: @forummember: First, we 've been over `destroy`: do **not** use it, use `close` instead. Second, if `document.forms.testForm.reset();` gives a JS error for whatever reason then you simply need to fix that.

Comment: Yes I have removed and tried it with close is well!!And also checked the `.reset()` method for javascript.But,cannot get any reason for the error.Sorry not very good at javascript debugging so,can you please guide me through!! :P

Comment: I have accepted the answer as it was well suggested way to get it done,but I have tried something else as I was a bit short on time.Please check the comment on the question added by me.Thanks for the support!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.dialog( "destroy" )
```

Remove the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

```
.dialog( "close" )
```

Close the dialog.

Comment: Yes I tried close but still I get the same error.So,this means there might be something else thats causing the problem.